# Why is only one user receiving a 302 status code?

Tags: netsuite, http-status-code-302

We have a user at our company who just started receiving a 302 status code when trying to access an item label via NetSuite. When he tries to pull up the label, it just pulls up a blank label. No one else is having this problem and he just started experiencing this yesterday. What could be the reason for just one person to have this issue?

Comment: Two common reasons a record won't come up for a user are: (1) The role they are using doesn't have access to that record type and (2) the record is not available in the subsidiary they have access to.

Comment: Hi @Brian, I don't think it's an access issue, as I had him log in to his NetSuite account on a different computer and the label pulled up successfully, no 302 status. So the issue appears to be linked to the computer itself, rather than the user.